# how to play videos in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, screen-orientation

Greetings for the Day,

I am doing total app in Portrait mode. But, In my app have videos tab. When select one video it is playing in Portrait mode only. But i want to play only in Landscape mode.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of `MPMoviePlayerController`, and implement these three methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; 
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Finally, use your MPMoviePlayerController subclass to play your videos.